# Returning data from EJB3 backend to jQuery table through Servlet and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a question that has been bothering me for a couple of weeks already. Namely, I have a Java EE EJB3 backend business engine, which is evoked by the Controller Servlet and returns specific data from the database to the Client. Now, in the Client I have a jqGrid, which needs to be populated with rather large quantities of data; large enough to be passed to the client in chunks. What i can't figure out is where to store all results returned by the business engine, so that the table can ask for a new page of data when we scroll through the results. Do we forward it to another servlet, which we then call from our table or rather send it to a stateful session bean, that will hold the current state and return the results to the table without calling the Controller Servlet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this would help in progressing my Final Year Project.

Regards

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

The browser can't call a stateful session bean directly. It always has to call a servlet. So, you have several choices:

- don't store anything anywhere: only return the rows that the grid asks for, and go back to the database when it asks the next chunk
- store the whole result in a stateful session bean, and have the servlet get the next chunks from this stateful bean
- store the results in the HTTP session directly, and have the servlet get the next chunks from the session

I prefer being as stateless as possible, because it makes the app more scalable, and often less complex, so my preference goes to the first solution, but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Will there not be any performance issues in the first solution? Because there will be many calls to the database. I tried to reduce the number of calls to the business engine to one and perform many small calls from the client to the servlet. Could I not store these results in the servlet for instance?

Comment: It depends. If the size of the table is huge, and its first results are interesting (think Google results) there is a very good chance that the user won't ever want to load the next ones, and loading the whole table from the database is a waste of time and memory. Note that you caoul also use an intermediate approach, where the query loads the IDs of all the rows of the table, and each chunk request loads the data corresponding to a subset of the IDs. Such a chunk request would thus be very fast, and the memory consumption would stay reasonable.

Comment: When it comes to my application, this is not the case. The user will want to scroll through all results possibly and in one query there can be 50 or 100 results and in another one let's say a 1000. I am returning a CachedRowSet, from the business engine, which enables dividing results into chunks or pages. I think I'm gonna go for the Stateful Session bean option, into which i'll inject all results and then query results bit by bit from the servlet.